# Proving that a set is a vector space - conflicting solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I was going over a question in the book "Linear Algebra" by Hoffman and Kunze, and came upon this problem. It goes as follows:

"Let V be the set of all pairs $(x, y)$ of real numbers, and let $F$ be the field of real numbers. Define

$$(x, y) + (x_1, y_1) = (x + x_1, y + y_1)$$
$$c(x, y) = (cx, y)$$

Is $V$, with these operations, a vector space over the field of real numbers?"

I checked and all the axioms seem to hold. However, I found one solution online that claims that it is not a vector space because:

$$(0, 2) = (0, 1) + (0, 1) = 2(0, 1) = (2∙0, 1) = (0, 1)$$

which is a contradiction, clearly.

Another solution I found shows that the axioms, as I found, are indeed satisfied.

Can anyone explain why the axioms seem to hold yet there is a contradiction? Or did I miss something when checking the axioms and, in turn, made a mistake? Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The vector addition operation is the same as that of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with its standard vector space structure, so there aren't going to be issues with the vector addition operation satisfying the required axioms.

Thus, our attention should be on the scalar multiplication. Axioms 4(a), 4(b), and 4(c) in Hoffman & Kunze are all satisfied, but the last, 4(d), is not. In other words, the axiom $(c_1+c_2)\alpha = c_1\alpha + c_2\alpha$ for all vectors $\alpha$ and scalars $c_1,c_2$ isn't satisfied.

The disproof that you give in the body of your question is exactly such a counterexample. I.e.,
$$(0,1) = 2(0,1) = (1+1)(0,1) \neq 1(0,1) + 1(0,1) = (0,1)+(0,1) = (0,2)$$

Comment: Ah makes sense! I think where I went wrong was when I said:

$(cx + dx, y) = (cx, y) + (dx, y)$ for c,d in F

Comment: Yes, that is indeed false according to the given definition of vector addition.

Answer (score 0):

One of your axioms should be $(c_1+c_2)v=c_1v+c_2v$.  That axiom isn't satisfied by this definition of scalar multiplication.

**Edited to state the correct distributive axiom that fails.**

Comment: It's true, $c(v+w) = (cv_x+cw_x, v_y+w_y) = (cv_x,v_y) + (cw_x,w_y) = cv + cw$

Comment: Isn't it though: For $a = (x1, y1), b = (x2, y2) and c$ in F, 

$c(a + b) = c((x1, y1) + (x2, y2)) = (c(x1 + x2, y1 + y2) = (cx1 + cx2, y1 + y2) = (cx1$ $, y1) + (cx2, y2) = c(x1, y1) + c(x2 + y2) = ca + cb$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Corrected.

Comment: @TRONIIX Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

For a vector space, you have $0\textbf{v} = \textbf{0} \forall \textbf{v}$, which is not the case for this set, hence it cannot be a vector space